# Linear operator $T$ on a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Question:

> A linear operator $T$ on a finite dimensional vector space is
>   diagonalizable if and only if the multiplicity of each eigenvalue
>   $\lambda$ equals the dimension of $E_\lambda$.

According to me the answer should be $true$, but my book says otherwise, and so, I know that I am probably wrong, but I can't figure out, what am I missing ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The multiplicity of each eigenvalue $\lambda$ in what? The characteristic polynomial? Then that's true.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think it should be the characteristic polynomial, though my book doesn't specify anything, i have copied the question as it is, from the book.Also what do you mean by "in what"? In What else can an eigenvalue have multiplicity ?

Comment: In the minimal polynomial. And if the multiplicity of each eigenvalue $\lambda$ in the minimal polynomial equals the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace, then the operator need not be diagonalisable (and if the operator is diagonalisable, the dimension of the eigenspace can be different from the multiplicity in the minimal polynomial).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just understood what the author(s) meant.

If you consider a linear operator $T\colon V \to V$ where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $k$ that is not algebraically closed, then not all zeros of the characteristic polynomial $\chi_T$ of $T$ need to lie in $k$.

If only the zeros of $\chi_T$ that lie in $k$ are considered eigenvalues, then indeed $T$ need not be diagonalisable if the dimension of $E_\lambda$ equals the multiplicity of $\lambda$ as a zero of $\chi_T$, for example consider $T \colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by multiplication with

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The characteristic polynomial is

$$\chi_T(X) = X^3 - X^2 + X - 1 = (X-1)(X^2+1) = (X-1)(X-i)(X+i),$$

and the only real eigenvalue is $1$, the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace is $1$, as is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue. But $T$ is not diagonalisable over $\mathbb{R}$ (since it has non-real eigenvalues).

If you consider every zero of the characteristic polynomial (in an algebraic closure of $k$) as an eigenvalue, then you have the simple characterisation that $T$ is diagonalisable if and only if $\dim E_\lambda$ equals the multiplicity of $X-\lambda$ in the characteristic polynomial. (And things like this are why a lot of people consider every zero of the characteristic polynomial an eigenvalue; the theory becomes much simpler then.)

Comment: It makes sense now, thank you.